# Mouse cursor tracking software with data export

Tags: windows, mouse, metrics

I'm looking to record some data about cursor movements that will be correlated with other sensor data collected by another system.  I hope to learn something about the relationship of the physical motions of a computer mouse and the cursor motion when used by the average user.

I have software to record the physical mouse that records the sensor data in a CSV file at a fairly short time interval (on the order of 100hz).  **What I need is a piece of software that can record similar data about the cursor position on the computer screen vs time intervals (faster than 30Hz sampling preferred)).**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Python script. As long as you also install [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/). using the [GetCursorInfo Function](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32gui__GetCursorInfo_meth.html)

```
flags, hcursor, (x,y) = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()
```

Alternatively, [This Link](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Mouse_position) will give you the codes for accessing mouse data from various languages. Use whichever works faster tham 30Hz for you.